# Java DOM comments ordering

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, comments

I've made recently a parser using Java's DOM parser that loads up an xmls and correcting some elements, attributes, etc..
The problem is the output format doesnt keeps the comments the way i'd like them to be.

Here's whats happening:

```diff
@@ -2107,7 +2121,8 @@
        <set name="enchant_enabled" val="1" />
        <set name="is_freightable" val="false" />
        <skills>
-           <skill id="3599" level="1" /> <!-- Polearm Multi-attack -->
+           <skill id="3599" level="1" />
+           <!-- Polearm Multi-attack -->
        </skills>
```

I couldn't find a way to keep comments on the right side of the element.
I also wanted to create new comments and i could put them either in before the element or after but not right next to it.

is there a way i could preserve such order?

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found library called  [DecentXML](https://bitbucket.org/digulla/decentxml) And it helped me achieve what i wanted.

```java
private void writeElement(Element parentNode, Element newNode, String comment)
{
    try
    {
        if (comment != null)
        {
            parentNode.addNodes(new Text("\t"), newNode, new Text(" "), new Comment(" " + comment + " "), new Text("\n\t\t"));
        }
        else
        {
            parentNode.addNodes(new Text("\t"), newNode, new Text("\n\t\t"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LOGGER.warn("Error while writing element", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: There you go @PaulKaram

Answer (score 0):

No; semantically they are the same XML file, and you have no control over how those elements are going to be rendered. You'd have to write your own post-processor to re-write the XML file if you wanted to achieve this effect.